# analyzing changesets on checkin with teamcity

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, continuous-integration, resharper, teamcity

Our project uses visual studio 2012 with TFS, resharper, and teamcity. We are using MS build too. 
We already have a CI build configured to run on every checkin with teamcity.

I'm looking for a way to get a report or warning (not a build failure) if anyone checks in a file with the string "debugger;" in it.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Is there a plugin or off the shelf tool that will do this? There are so many different tools available I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Technically a custom PowerShell script will be able to do this.
I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve. Why are you searching for files containing "debugger" in their content?

Comment: tl;dr - boss asked for it. I've so far cobbled together a build step that runs a command file that uses the %ystem.teamcity.build.changedFiles.file% to query TFS, do a diff against the previous build, then a find string against the dif, and add a build artifact if someone checked in a 'debugger;'. Still nailing down the regex, as I'm getting some false positives, and then need to figure out how to get teamcity to notify me in some way when there are build artifacts (or have it generate a report).